# Ideal as subrepresentation of algebra

Tags: representation-theory

I am confused the statement that ideal is a subrepresentation of regular representation of an algebra.

Actually I am not very clear about the definition of regular representation of an algebra, although I do know the regular representation of a finite group. But since an algebra may have infinite many elements, how do we define the vector space of the regular representation? I do tried to google, but just can not find satisfactory answer. Could somebody helps to clarify this? Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the vector space: a representation of an algebra is just a module, not necessarily a vector space.  Since an algebra is already an abelian group, it serves as a module over itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (left) regular representation of an algebra $A$ is the algebra itself (by left multiplication). Let $I$ be an ideal, then we have that for any $i\in I$ and $a\in A$, $ai\in I$. Therefore, the ideal $I$ is a subrepresentation.

Comment: So $p(a)$ is not an endomorphism of some vector space V but just an endomorphism of A itself?

Comment: @Learning $p(a)$ is the endomorphism of the vector space underlying $A$ given by the left multiplication by $a$ (using the algebra structure on $A$).